# SQLite query to find specific sequence of items stored individually in tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, sequence

Let's say I have an SQLite database of goods to go on a train.
My database is organized like this:

```
Merchandise table
Merchandise ID
Name (some other info)

Train table
Train ID
(some other info)

Loading table
Train ID
Merchandise ID
Car number (0 for the locomotive and going down from there).
```

What would be the proper query if I want to find a specific sequence of cars. Let's say I to know what trains have two cars of toys following each other followed by one car of tomatoes followed by one car of dirt.

(My application is not really like that, but this makes for a simpler analogy of what I really need...)

EDIT... after some head scratching...

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM
 (SELECT * FROM merchandise JOIN loading ON merchandise.merchandise_id=loading.merchandise_id WHERE name="toys") AS car1
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM merchandise JOIN loading ON merchandise.merchandise_id=loading.merchandise_id WHERE name="toys") AS car2
    ON (car2.position=car1.position+1) AND car1.train_id=car2.train_id
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM merchandise JOIN loading ON merchandise.merchandise_id=loading.merchandise_id WHERE name="tomatoes") AS car3
    ON (car3.position=car2.position+1) AND car2.train_id=car3.train_id
  JOIN (SELECT * FROM merchandise JOIN loading ON merchandise.merchandise_id=loading.merchandise_id WHERE name="dirt") AS car4
    ON (car4.position=car3.position+1) AND car3.train_id=car4.train_id
```

I need to do a bit more testing, but that seems to work OK.

Not sure if there is a more efficient way though (would need to look at the details of the 'EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN')

Comment: The basic approach seems quite reasonable to me. I might consider reducing the number of joins by passing the merchandise pieces as IDs, not names, but that might well depend on your app's design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if there's a *good* way to do this, entirely from sql.  However, here's one was able to get it to work.  That being said, I've a few caveats I'll mention after the query:

```
select
    sub.train_id
from
    (   -- We need a sub-query here to we can sort
        -- *before* the group by (and group_concat)
        select
            l.train_id,
            m.name
        from
            loading l
            join merchandise m
                on l.merchandise_id = m.id
        order by
            l.car_no
    ) as sub
group by
    sub.train_id
having
    -- If you want no other items, you'll want to remove the '%s's
    -- Also, you could use ids instead of names to make this a little more robust
    group_concat(sub.name) like '%toys,toys,tomatoes,dirt%'
```

Ok, so here's what wrong with this:

- group_concat will probably only work for sequences up to a certain length.  I've not used it much in sqlite, but mysql has (or had a while ago) a limit of something like 256 chars.  I'm not sure of any limitations sqlite has, but that's something to keep in mind.
- while this works, and the ordering seems to be preserved in the `group_concat` (sqlite version 3.7.7.1), the docs explicitly state: "[The order of the concatenated elements is arbitrary](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html)"

All that being said, I'd probably just try and find this programmatically, but this is a clever way that *seems* to work for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found a way to do it (see my edits in the question). I can see what you are trying to do, I'm afraid doing the group_concat, to basically make every "train" into a string is going to end up being a very expensive query. Although the one I did with all the joins may not be much better... would love to hear if you have any comment.

Comment: I would think your approach could be a bit faster (it should be able to use indexes), but it obviously more of a pain to construct.  I think 3 or 4 joins isn't a problem, but I don't know what happens if you need 20 or more joins, so I'm not sure which would run better in a scenario like that (not sure if you need sequences that long or not).  I'd say run both types of queries and see which one runs faster.